# Is the topologist's sine curve (without boundary) path connected?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Consider the set
$$
S = \left\{\left(x,\sin\frac 1x\right) : x\in(0,1]\right\}.
$$
Then $S=f((0,1])$ where $f(x) = \left(x,\sin\frac1x\right)$. Since $f$ is continuous and $(0,1]$ is path connected, it should follow that $S$ is path connected. But this runs counter to the well-known fact that the topologist's sine curve is not path connected. Is it the case that this set $S$ *is* path connected, it's just that the "topologist's sine curve" is actually $S\cup\{(0,0)\}$ (which most definitely is *not* path connected)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is path connected.  In my experience, the "topologist's sine curve" usually refers to $S\cup\{0\}\times[-1,1]$ (i.e., the closure of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$), though I wouldn't be surprised if you sometimes see it used to refer to $S\cup\{(0,0)\}$ or (more rarely, in contexts where it is convenient to do so) to $S$.

Comment: This is what I thought, thanks. Munkres defines the topologist's sine curve as $\overline S$, as you wrote. Sorry for the trivial question, this was just a sanity check :)

Comment: Are you sure about the $\times [-1,1]$ part (for the usual definition) ?

Comment: @nicomezi: Yes?  What else would it be?

Comment: Because the definition given by the OP is clearly the one I met almost everytime. The wikipedia page of that curve also gives that one.

Comment: @nicomezi: Well, as I said, I'm not surprised that you have encountered that definition.  My own experience is that the full closure is the usual definition, but it seems that this is not universal.

Comment: @nicomezi I second EricWofsey opinion that we include the vertical line segment on $y$-axis $-1,1]$. I just looked up [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), it only includes the origin apart from the graph of $f(x)$ (not the whole vertical line segment)...but it is not just the graph. Wikipedia lists two versions, one called closed topologist's sine curve (includes all of $[-1,1]$), and extended topologist's sine curve, adding on top of that a horizontal closed interval at $y=1$. wolfram.com includes the negative part of the $x$-axis, instead of just the origin.

Comment: Wikipedia call the version with the $y$-axis $[-1,1]$ the "closed" version of the curve. This is not a detail since this version cannot be seen as the graph of a function from an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but only the closure of it, while the definition used by Wolfram or the first given by wikipedia can. @Mirko

Comment: On my part, I am surprised that you mostly encountered the closed version of the curve as the standard definition, because of the reason I gave in my previous comment. Hence my question. @EricWofsey

Comment: I just want to add that my opinion is supported by the fact that this example is usually taught when people begin to have some tools in real analysis, then hopefully they will understand that even regular functions can generate pathological examples in topology. And that the notions contained in that field are subtle, so they have to pay attention to the objects they consider. The closed version can help to go further, or to emphasize on some properties, but the definition without the $y$ axis part seems more appropriate as a standard one to me.